# How to properly run python-telegram-bot together with fastapi?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, fastapi, python-telegram-bot

I built a Python framework to easily build Telegram bots based on the python-telegram-bot module. Then I added fastapi to it so that framework plugins could easily provide web interfaces.

But in order to get both working I needed to use the nest_asyncio module, which I don't like. I'd like to do it "properly" and not use that but I'm not able to get it working without it. My question is, how to get rid of it?

You can check out the full code [here](https://github.com/Endogen/tgbf2). Below is a reduced example:

```
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
import uvicorn

from threading import Thread

from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse

from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, CallbackContext


class WebAppWrapper(Thread):

    def __init__(self, port: int = 5000):
        self.router = APIRouter()
        self.port = port
        self.app = None

        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.app = FastAPI()
        self.app.include_router(self.router)

        html_content = """
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Some HTML in here</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Look ma! HTML!</h1>
            </body>
        </html>
        """

        @self.app.get('/', include_in_schema=False)
        async def root(): return HTMLResponse(content=html_content, status_code=200)

        uvicorn.run(self.app, host="0.0.0.0", port=self.port)


class TelegramBot:

    def __init__(self):
        self.bot = None
        self.web = None

    async def run(self):
        self.bot = (
            Application.builder()
            .token("SOME_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN")  # TODO: Enter Telegram Bot Token
            .build()
        )

        self.web = WebAppWrapper(port=5000)

        async def test_callback(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
            await update.message.reply_text("pong")

        self.bot.add_handler(CommandHandler("ping", test_callback, block=False))

        self.web.start()

        self.bot.run_polling(drop_pending_updates=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nest_asyncio.apply()
    
    asyncio.run(TelegramBot().run())
```